# What does the ~ symbol mean in search analytics in Google Search Console?

Tags: google-search-console

I'm using search analytics in GSC to figure out how many people access my site through Google on different devices. Sometimes when I do comparisons, I see a `~` as a value.

I assume it means the same as the value in the same row, but in the column to the left of the column containing the value.

Can anyone clarify this?

Comment: At first I thought it was infinity, but then I realized it probably was a number less than what the column can handle. For example, if .01 is the lowest value for the column, the squiggly was less than .01. I stopped looking at GA and SC the app formerly known as GWT. So I an going off of older memory from the memory of an old guy. That is as close to organic LSD as you can get. Who says it is good to be young?! No more scrounging around for your next high. Just place your glasses somewhere unusual.

Comment: FWIW the ~ is called a tilde

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Sometimes when I do comparisons, I see a `~` as a value.

It appears to indicate that the value is "not available".

From [Search Console Help - Search Analytics Report - Comparing your data](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6155685?hl=en):

> If you compare two groups, and a value is very rare in one group but not rare in the other group, the rare group will show **~** for that row to indicate that the number is not available. For example, if you compare query impressions between Germany and Thailand, the result row for "Deutsche Bundesbank" will probably show an impression number for Germany, and a **~** (not available) for Thailand. This is because the impression count for Thailand is at the end of a very long tail of results. It does not necessarily mean zero, but it is far down the list for that group. However, if you filter by the rare value (in this example "Deutsche Bundesbank"), you should see data values for both categories.

Also note:

> **Downloaded data unavailable/not a number values.** If you download the data in the report, any values shown as **~** or **-** (not available/not a number) on the report will be zeros in the downloaded data.

Comment: Good thing I asked my question because to me, "N/A" would mean not-available and "~" would normally mean infinite or approximate but with the way google does things, who knows... maybe they want to take over the world 100%.

Answer (score 1):

It's [a mathematical symbol meaning "approximately"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tilde#Mathematics). For instance, "there are ~10,000 URLs on my website".